# error CS0117: 'EditorUtility' does not contain a definition for 'RequestScriptReload'

Tags: unity-game-engine

In unity I keep on getting this error that keeps on bugging me, I tried to remove packages to leave one of these errors and it kept on going on and on, i am developing a game right now using unity engine and the errors are a big pain for me, this is the code that someone asked for, i dont really have much else to write other than this, stackoverlow isnt letting me just  post it because its too short

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;

namespace UnityEditor.SettingsManagement
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    /// <summary>
    /// A settings repository that stores data local to a Unity project.
    /// </summary>
    [Serializable]
    public sealed class PackageSettingsRepository : ISettingsRepository
    {
        const string k_PackageSettingsDirectory = "ProjectSettings/Packages";
        const bool k_PrettyPrintJson = true;

        bool m_Initialized;

        [SerializeField]
        string m_Name;

        [SerializeField]
        string m_Path;

        [SerializeField]
        SettingsDictionary m_Dictionary = new SettingsDictionary();

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor sets the serialized data path.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="package">
        /// The package name.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="name">
        /// A name for this settings file. Settings are saved in `ProjectSettings/Packages/{package}/{name}.json`.
        /// </param>
        public PackageSettingsRepository(string package, string name)
        {
            m_Name = name;
            m_Path = GetSettingsPath(package, name);
            m_Initialized = false;

            AssemblyReloadEvents.beforeAssemblyReload += Save;
            EditorApplication.quitting += Save;
        }

        void Init()
        {
            if (m_Initialized)
                return;

            m_Initialized = true;

            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                m_Dictionary = null;
                var json = File.ReadAllText(path);
                EditorJsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite(json, this);
                if(m_Dictionary == null)
                    m_Dictionary = new SettingsDictionary();
            }
        }

        /// <value>
        /// This repository implementation is relevant to the Project scope.
        /// </value>
        /// <inheritdoc cref="ISettingsRepository.scope"/>
        public SettingsScope scope
        {
            get { return SettingsScope.Project; }
        }

        /// <value>
        /// The full path to the settings file.
        /// This corresponds to `Unity Project/Project Settings/Packages/com.unity.package/name`.
        /// </value>
        /// <inheritdoc cref="ISettingsRepository.path"/>
        public string path
        {
            get { return m_Path; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The name of this settings file.
        /// </summary>
        public string name
        {
            get { return m_Name; }
        }

        // Cannot call FindFromAssembly from a constructor or field initializer
//        static string CreateSettingsPath(Assembly assembly, string name)
//        {
//            var info = PackageManager.PackageInfo.FindForAssembly(assembly);
//            return string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}.json", k_PackageSettingsDirectory, info.name, name);
//        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get a path for a settings file relative to the calling assembly package directory.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="packageName">The name of the package requesting this setting.</param>
        /// <param name="name">An optional name for the settings file. Default is "Settings."</param>
        /// <returns>A package-scoped path to the settings file within Project Settings.</returns>
        public static string GetSettingsPath(string packageName, string name = "Settings")
        {
            return string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}.json", k_PackageSettingsDirectory, packageName, name);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Save all settings to their serialized state.
        /// </summary>
        /// <inheritdoc cref="ISettingsRepository.Save"/>
        public void Save()
        {
            Init();

            if (!File.Exists(path))
            {
                var directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
                Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
            }

#if UNITY_2019_3_OR_NEWER
            if (!AssetDatabase.IsOpenForEdit(path))
            {
                if (!AssetDatabase.MakeEditable(path))
                {
                    Debug.LogWarning($"Could not save package settings to {path}");
                    return;
                }
            }
#endif

            try
            {
                File.WriteAllText(path, EditorJsonUtility.ToJson(this, k_PrettyPrintJson));
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
            {
                Debug.LogWarning($"Could not save package settings to {path}");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Set a value for key of type T.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key">The settings key.</param>
        /// <param name="value">The value to set. Must be serializable.</param>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Type of value.</typeparam>
        /// <inheritdoc cref="ISettingsRepository.Set{T}"/>
        public void Set<T>(string key, T value)
        {
            Init();
            m_Dictionary.Set<T>(key, value);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get a value with key of type T, or return the fallback value if no matching key is found.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key">The settings key.</param>
        /// <param name="fallback">If no key with a value of type T is found, this value is returned.</param>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Type of value to search for.</typeparam>
        /// <inheritdoc cref="ISettingsRepository.Get{T}"/>
        public T Get<T>(string key, T fallback = default(T))
        {
            Init();
            return m_Dictionary.Get<T>(key, fallback);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Does the repository contain a setting with key and type.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key">The settings key.</param>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The type of value to search for.</typeparam>
        /// <returns>True if a setting matching both key and type is found, false if no entry is found.</returns>
        /// <inheritdoc cref="ISettingsRepository.ContainsKey{T}"/>
        public bool ContainsKey<T>(string key)
        {
            Init();
            return m_Dictionary.ContainsKey<T>(key);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Remove a key value pair from the settings repository.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key"></param>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <inheritdoc cref="ISettingsRepository.Remove{T}"/>
        public void Remove<T>(string key)
        {
            Init();
            m_Dictionary.Remove<T>(key);
```

Comment: Well, [yes it does](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUtility.RequestScriptReload.html) so check for typos. Please add your code and the exact error message including the stracktrace

Comment: im going to add the code, im sorry if i do something wrong, im new to coding

Comment: Please add the exact error message and stacktrace from the console ... in your code I see no usage or mention of `EditorUtility.RequestScriptReload`

Answer (score 0):

By the definition of ['RequestScriptReload'](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUtility.RequestScriptReload.html) :

"*The Unity Editor reloads script assemblies asynchronously on the next frame. This resets the state of all the scripts, but Unity does not compile any code that has changed since the previous compilation.*"

That means that your problem is probably with something that you changed.

You can try:

1. Going back to the last time everything wored and go on from there.
2. Closing all of you unity and scripting applications and opening it again.